# Config options in Keras with CNTK backend

Tags: python, keras, cntk

While writing code in Python with Keras and Theano backend you could setup a config file for Theano specifying the amount of preallocated memory with cnmem attribute. Is there a similar functionality for CNTK backend?

In fact, is there any config functionality for CNTK backend while using only Python?